# Docker Build: xz(stdin): File format not recognized

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Hi total Docker noob here, is there a dependency i can run so this error goes away?

```
    Step 19/40 : RUN curl -OL https://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/${ghc%[a-z]}/ghc-${ghc}-x86_64-deb7-linux.tar.xz | tar -xJf- &&   cd ghc-${ghc} &&   ./configure && make install
     ---> Running in 0141996d759f
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   161  100   161    0     0    335      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   336
    100 85.5M  100 85.5M    0     0   308k      0  0:04:44  0:04:44 --:--:--  358k
    xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
    tar: Child returned status 1
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    The command '/bin/sh -c curl -OL https://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/${ghc%[a-z]}/ghc-${ghc}-x86_64-deb7-linux.tar.xz | tar -xJf- &&   cd ghc-${ghc} &&   ./configure && make install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `-O` option to **curl** that writes to disk instead of stdout.

Try with: `curl -L https://...`

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: `/bin/sh: line 0: cd: ghc-7.10.3b: No such file or directory`

Comment: `The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L https://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/${ghc%[a-z]}/ghc-${ghc}-x86_64-deb7-linux.tar.xz | tar -xJf- &&   cd ghc-${ghc} &&   ./configure && make install' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Check the main directory of the tarball you're downloading and change the `cd ghc-...` command accordingly.

Comment: that was it. -______- thank you, the repo i'm working off of as i'm coming to realize is poorly kept.

Comment: It's ok.  Mark this question as answered.